# Adding extra p and span tag for html emailing

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook.com

My html email layout as below;

[image]

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <table width="602" height="556" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" colspan="5">
                    <a style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" href="http://www.google.com">
                        <img src="images/img_01.jpg" alt="" height="91" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="602" >
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" colspan="5">
                    <img src="images/img_02.jpg" alt="" height="360" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="602" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;">
                    <a style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" href="http://www.google.com">
                        <img src="images/img_03.jpg" alt="" height="57" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="118" >
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;">
                    <a style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" href="http://www.google.com">
                        <img src="images/img_04.jpg" alt="" height="57" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="96" >
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;">
                    <img src="images/img_05.jpg" alt="" height="57" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="194" >
                </td>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;">
                    <a style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" href="http://www.google.com">
                        <img src="images/img_06.jpg" alt="" height="57" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="110" >
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;">
                    <img src="images/img_07.jpg" alt="" height="57" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="84" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" colspan="3">
                    <img src="images/img_08.jpg" alt="" height="48" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="408" >
                </td>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;">
                    <a style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" href="http://www.google.com">
                        <img src="images/img_09.jpg" alt="" height="48" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="110" >
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;">
                    <img src="images/img_10.jpg" alt="" height="48" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="84" >
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Above code work fine for gmail, outlook 2007, outlook.com. But if I forward this mail from outlook 2007 to outlook.com, email break as like this;

[image]

Outlook adding extra p and span tag to anchor tag for image  and gives them style. So my layout, break as above image.

Original Code;

```
<td style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" colspan="5">
    <a style="line-height:0; font-size:0px;" href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="imagepath" alt="" height="91" style="display:block; border:none; line-height:0;" width="602" >
    </a>
</td>
```

Styled Code (after forwarding mail);

```
<td colspan="5" style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
    <p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:0%;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="">
            <span style="font-size:1.0pt;color:blue;text-decoration:none;">
                <img border="0" width="602" height="91" id="ecx_x0000_i1034" src="imagepath" class="">
            </span>
        </a>
        <span style="font-size:1.0pt;"></span>
    </p>
</td>
```

**JsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/zc7nL/

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to prevent Outlook adding the `<p>` tags, we just have to find ways to zero them out. Try adding `margin: 0; padding: 0;` inline to all your image tags and add `#outlook a {padding:0;}` to your header style tag. Also removing the space between your anchor and image tags may possibly stop the spans from appearing. Not 100% sure, but worth a try.

If none of that works, try targeting `.ecxMsoNormal` in your style tag as you would for the web. Any styles you apply there should take affect as Outlook reads it (unlike Gmail).